# Php input box value is said to be !ISSET although it has a value

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

I'm using Ajax with PHP for an HTML form. Here is my HTML form.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
Student Category :
<input type="radio" name="category"  value="Full Time"    onclick='showUser(this.value)'/>Full Time</br>
<input type="radio" name="category"  value="Part Time" onclick='showUser(this.value)'/>Part Time</br>

Index Number :<div id="txtHint"></div><br/>
<button type="submit" name="save" id="save" class="btn">SUBMIT</button></form>
```

I used Ajax with student category and Index Number. If the user selects the first radio button, a text box with default value of "MPhil/FT/2013/" will be displayed in Index Number. If second radio button is selected, default value will be "MPhil/PT/2013/".

Here is my Ajax and JS code for it:

```
<script>
  function showUser(str)
  {
    if (str=="")
    {
       document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
      return;
    } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
       xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
     xmlhttp.open("GET","getUser.php?q="+str,true);
     xmlhttp.send();
  }
</script>
```

getUser.php file contains the following code.

```
<?php
  $q = $_GET['q'];
  $r =  date("Y");

  if ($q == 'Full Time') {
    echo "<input type='text' name='reg' class='form-control' value='M.Phil/FT/$r/' />";
  } else if ($q == 'Part Time') {
    echo "<input type='text' name='reg' class='form-control' value='M.Phil/PT/$r/' />";
  }
?>
```

The code to get form value(contains in the same page of html form)

```
 <?php
   if (isset($_POST['save'])) { 
     if (isset($_POST['category'])) {
       $d=($_POST['category']);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['reg'])) { 
       $a=$_POST['reg'];
       echo $a;
    }
  }
```

Though input box 'reg' has a value, when submitted the form $a will not be printed. That is, it goes as `(!isset($_POST['reg']))`. I want to get my input box value. But it is said to be !isset. Can somebody please help me with this? 
P.S- all above displayed codes are in one file except the 3rd code. 3rd code is in getUser.php file.
Thank You.

Comment: Are you sure, your dynamic input box is displayed?

Comment: Yes. But only when a radio button is selected. If not, no input text box is displayed.

Comment: in your 4th code insert this line at the top and check if you are able to get all request parameters:   var_dump($_REQUEST);

Comment: An error is displayed as undefined variable a. And the rest of the code will be printed like array(15) { ["category"]=> string(9) "Full Time" ["name1"]=> string(0) "" ["name2"]=> string(0) ""

Comment: now try with print_r($_REQUEST); and paste the output here

Comment: I m able to get the expected output in my browser..which php version are you using?

Comment: php 5.3.1 I posted here only half of my long code. I have other inputs and php codes in my file. I doesn't work in that. But i tried this by creating new files and including only these code. And it WORKED! But in my original file it will display as array(15) { ["category"]=> string(9) "Full Time" ["name1"]=> string(0) "" ["name2"]=> string(0) "" ["NIC"]=> string(0) "" ["date_register"]=>  and undefined variable a.

Comment: The problem is in that remaining code and not in this...

Comment: I will try again. But the code worked before i added the ajax code to get input box value according to radio button selected. That is when it a normal input box was there and not a dynamic one.